# maven - how to deploy non-jar files

Tags: maven, deployment, jar, jenkins, archiva

In my project I have many modules.

One of the modules requires a `jar` file to be deployed to the repository which it does fine.

The others involve every other kind of file: `zip`, `kar` etc.

I can see the `zip` get uploaded if I look for it via the terminal but if I browse `Archiva` it is not there.

The `kar` file, for example, does not need to be built but it's being worked on and is currently manually uploaded to the repository (`Archiva`). This is not desirable.

Each module has a `POM` and each `POM` uploads empty `jar` files to `Archiva` when it is built (with `Jenkins`). How can I avoid that? And can I copy files to `Archiva` without them having to be built into a `jar` file?

Comment: what do you mean with "If I browse Archiva"? the real browsing .../repository/... or the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a try to "maven-deploy-plugin"
Invoke a maven target in jenkins with this plugin and provide the suitable parameters.

You would also need the repository to be added in you settings.xml if your repository requires login credentials and then use the ID, you mentioned in settings.xml, in the maven target.

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file
-Durl=<artifact-repo URL>
-Dfile=<name of the file>
-DgroupId=<Group Id>
-DartifactId=<Artifact Id>
-Dversion=<VERSION>
-Dpackaging=<packaging Type>
-DrepositoryId=<ID as mentioned in settings.xml>
```

Hope this may be of some help.